# How to get data between two dates in node js

Tags: node.js

Like I have a group of data of different dates and I want to have data between two particular date like start date and end date and I want data between these two dates. And I don't really have any idea how to do so can I get any insight about it..

Comment: In Javascript, [timestamps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) are simply double-precision numbers holding the number of milliseconds since a defined moment in the past. So `if (start_time <= item_time && item_time < end_time) { ... }` is a good starting point. But you haven't told us enough about your problem to get any more specific advice.

Answer (score 0):

```
const start_date = new Date(item.start_date).getTime();
const end_date = new Date(item.end_date).getTime();

const diff = end_date - start_date;
```

Now you have the different of two dates in timestamp type. You can check here for more information about timestamp https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time